# Memory management iOS/ARC

Tags: objective-c

I am reading some book ([link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321821521)) which says following: *"All this automatic clean-up and memory recycling occurs simply by setting `items` to nil. That’s the power of ARC."*.
This is said about following code:

```
    // create array
    NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  
    
    // add random BNRItems to the array
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        BNRItem *p = [BNRItem randomItem];  
        [items addObject:p];  
    }
    
    // print items in array
    for (BNRItem *item in items) {
        NSLog(@"%@", item);
    }
    


    items = nil;
```

It basically briefly explains how by setting `items = nil` all objects above get destroyed correctly.
My question is:

- say I am using ARC, and *I don't* set `items = nil` - does this mean
  I will have memory leak?

I tested by overriding dealloc of BNRItem and printing some info, dealloc seems to be called properly on all BNRitems even if I don't set `items = nil`.

Comment: Your method may seem to work in some cases but we need ARC to automatically clean up objects otherwise there could be many mem leak issues.

Comment: That is not what the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the reference to `nil` tells ARC that you're finished with it and allows it to clean up straight away. Not setting it to `nil` doesn't mean that it won't be cleaned up, it just might not be cleaned up so quickly.

You do also need to note the difference between local variables like in your test (because they are always cleaned at the end of the defining scope) and instance variables (which can live for as long as the owning instance if not nilled).

Comment: Yes, I see I think I got confused by this sentence in the book: "All this automatic clean-up and memory recycling occurs simply by setting items to nil. That’s the power of ARC." - this sentence says setting items to nil will clean up all stuff, but it does not mean cleaning won't happen if one does not set items = nil.

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not leak. ARC will perform the release message when it goes out of scope. The timing/sequence is not specific for optimization purposes. Technically, it has the liberty to use autorelease instead.

Comment: Yes, I see I think I got confused by this sentence in the book: "All this automatic clean-up and memory recycling occurs simply by setting items to nil. That’s the power of ARC." - this sentence says setting items to nil will clean up all stuff, but it does not mean cleaning won't happen if one does not set items = nil.

Comment: @user2568508 easy to misconstrue -- ARC will also release your ivars in -dealloc.